# Oracle 18 c DATA difference between Windows and Linux installations

Tags: linux, oracle

We have oracle 18c installed on windows and linux. Same version. Windows/oracle is able to pull the data in right format from sql server DB link view which has nvarchar datatypes, Vs Linux/oracle data is coming as special characters.  Windows  and Linux have same NLS NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16 and NLS_CHARACTERSET  AL32UTF8. Any idea why we are getting special characters in Linux/Oracle ? Any environment variables that we have to check? Also we see the excel reports working on windows are not working on linux/oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least check `NLS_LANG` which is an operating system setting on Windows (environment variable or registry key) and an environment variable on Linux.

Comment: Both places its AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252. Still the same issue